# Finding a page for text amends in a Magento shop

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url-routing

I've been asked to change some text on what appears to be a static page on a [Magento](http://magento.com/) powered site. The page is located at `/delivery`.

The `/delivery` URL is publicly accessible. I just don't know where it lives within the system. I'm not sure whether the page lives in a file or is being brought in through the Magento framework from a database or other.

Within the Magento Admin panel there is no **Pages** menu in the **CMS** dropdown. Furthermore, there aren't any references to `/delivery` in the **Catalogue > URL Rewrite Management**.

I have root access to the server, but the site was not built by me so I need to tread carefully. As far as I can tell there are no specific rewrites for `/delivery` in the Apache2 configurations. I *would* try a `grep` for a specific piece of text on that page, but the whole site is around the 20GB mark, so I would want to narrow down the possibilities first.

What other avenues of investigation would a Magento or other developer exhaust to find the text before trying to get in touch with the original developers?

Comment: What is it actually showing? Is it showing the webpage with the markup from the main template you use for the magento shop? Or does it look like plain stuff with information. Maybe it even is a physical path on in your magento installation folder

Comment: @Jordy Hi. It's definitely got the usual Magento fluff within it. Links, blocks etc. But I've searched **CMS > Static Blocks** also with no luck.

Comment: Have you also checked basic things like extensions etc? Maybe an extension is causing this, it could be lots of things really.

Comment: @Jordy how would I go about 'checking' extensions? I find it hard to believe that a Magento developer wouldn't have a list of 'usual suspect' locations.

Comment: You can temporarly rename the `app/code/community` and `app/code/local` folder to disable all the plugins at once. Then clear your cache and load the page and check if it's still there.

Comment: @Jordy The site is live and has quite a large customer base. As far as I'm aware there are no staging servers.

Comment: Anything can go wrong and you can't afford that to happen on your live server. I'd rather spend a bit of time on actually setting up a local environment for yourself so you can  try out some things and find the root of the problem.

Comment: @Jordy I feared this might be the case. The site is pretty large. I'm guessing I'll need to setup SQL etc. Can you recommend any migration tutorials/tools for Magento?

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so then I'd simply install WAMP. Then I would download the filebase and make an export of the database. Then import the database using mysql workbench (phpmyadmin is not recommended as Magento dbs are quite large). About migration tools, I am not 100% sure if there are, you'd have to search for these. I usually just follow the process above.

Comment: @Jordy Thanks for the above info. I'm on OSX so I'll find equivalent programs for these tasks.

Comment: According to your question it seems like it is a cms page.But i quite confused by the sentence that the pages are not showing under CMS menu? What do you mean of that.There is pages submenu under CMS menu in admin panel. Are you logging with the super user or you are provided with the login credentials with confined privilage?

Comment: @aton1004 It seems I probably have confined privileges.

Comment: I don't think there is any other possibilities of changing the content of CMS page without editing it. You have to get access to that to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's definately not a cms page, then try running this on shell

```
grep -R '<frontName>delivery</frontName>' /path/to/site/app/code/*
```

This should hopefully find the module using that frontname.  It could be however that the module has a configurable frontname, in which case you could connect to the data base and search for the value in the table;

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where value = "delivery"
```

Seems odd you don't have a link to cms pages in your admin, so while you're looking at the db, take a look at;

```
SELECT * FROM cms_page;
```

And confirm the delivery page isnt living there.

If the page is infact in the cms_page table, then it becomes a question of why you cant get to the tab.  First port of call would be to ask the person who created your admin account to check whether your user role has access to that particular feature, and if not, get it added.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have the password to access mysql. However, I did find an sql dump somewhere in the file system. On inspection, I noticed that there was a 'cms_page' entry for the `/delivery` content. So what are the possible reasons for the **Pages** menu being absent from the **CMS** dropdown in the Admin Panel?

Comment: are you logging in as a super admin?  it could be that your account uses a role that doesnt have access to the cms pages tab - if thats the case, ask the site admin to add cms pages to your user role.

Comment: Ok, I'll request an updated user role and report back with the results. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: This answer ultimately led me to the solution: the page was indeed a Magento 'CMS Page', and the admin credentials given to me had not been blessed with the ability to edit said pages. I have since gained access and I'm happily looking at the editable content albeit through Magento's drunken spectacles. Thanks again.